# FullCalendar wrong end time when render events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

On the screenshot below you can see my event starts from 8am-7pm:

[image]

The start time is correct on 8am, but the end time misses somewhere to 4pm.

My event object is this:

```
_end

    Moment { _isAMomentObject=true, _isUTC=true, _i="2014-08-19T19:00:00+00:00", more...}

_start

    Moment { _isAMomentObject=true, _isUTC=true, _i="2014-08-19T08:00:00+00:00", more...}

allDay

    false

end

    Moment { _isAMomentObject=true, _useUTC=true, _isUTC=true, more...}

start

    Moment { _isAMomentObject=true, _useUTC=true, _isUTC=true, more...}
```

`_start` and `_end` shows `08:00:00` and `19:00:00` respectively. `_i` value from `end` property is `"2014-08-19T19:00:00+00:00"` and `_i` value from `start` property is `"2014-08-19T08:00:00+00:00"`. What am i missing that the end time is not properly rendered?

**SOLVED**
Apparently i set `fc-events` to have `1em` padding. That makes the `height` calculation missed.